# Unable to clone repository

Tags: git, clone

While trying to clone a repository, I am getting following error:-

```
error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0
```

I am using https connection if this information is of use.

What I have tried :-

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

This didnot work out.

Additional details :- 
OS - Ubuntu 14.04,
Git Repo - BitBucket,
git version - 1.9.1

Edit :-

Result from :-
      GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git clone URL

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git clone <https:url>
Cloning into 'reponame'...
* Couldn't find host bitbucket.org in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 104.192.143.2...
* Connected to bitbucket.org (104.192.143.2) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*        server certificate verification OK
*        common name: bitbucket.org (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: 
*        start date: Tue, 03 May 2016 00:00:00 GMT

*        expire date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 12:00:00 GMT

*        issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*        compression: NULL
*        cipher: AES-128-CBC
*        MAC: SHA256
> GET reponame.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.9.1
Host: bitbucket.org
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Bitbucket.org HTTP"
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2016 09:31:20 GMT
< X-Git-Mode: pull
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 12
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host bitbucket.org left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: '<url here>/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack'
* Couldn't find host bitbucket.org in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host bitbucket.org: 0xb5e5f0
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host bitbucket.org
* Connected to bitbucket.org (104.192.143.2) port 443 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user_name'
> GET /reponame/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic c3JlZWthbnRoX25jOg==
User-Agent: git/1.9.1
Host: bitbucket.org
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
* Server nginx/1.6.2 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Bitbucket.org HTTP"
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/plain
< X-Usage-Output-Ops: 0
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2016 09:31:21 GMT
< X-Usage-User-Time: 0.009855
< X-Usage-System-Time: 0.003753
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< X-View-Name: bitbucket.gitweb.application
< Connection: Closed
< X-Usage-Input-Ops: 0
< 
* Closing connection 0
Password for <url here>
* Couldn't find host bitbucket.org in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 104.192.143.2...
* Connected to bitbucket.org (104.192.143.2) port 443 (#1)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* SSL re-using session ID
*        server certificate verification OK
*        common name: bitbucket.org (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: 
*        start date: Tue, 03 May 2016 00:00:00 GMT

*        expire date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 12:00:00 GMT

*        issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*        compression: NULL
*        cipher: AES-128-CBC
*        MAC: SHA256
* Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
> GET /reponame.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic c3JlZWthbnRoX25jOnNyZWVrYW50aGhlcmU=
User-Agent: git/1.9.1
Host: bitbucket.org
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< bbr1wikiprivate: 0
< bbr1private: 1
* Server nginx/1.6.2 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
< X-Usage-Output-Ops: 0
< bbr1reposlug: reponame
< bbr1hasadmin: 0
< bbr1scm: git
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2016 09:31:37 GMT
< X-Usage-User-Time: 0.016693
< X-Usage-System-Time: 0.004990
< bbuserid: 5740059
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< bbr1hasread: 1
< bbr1ownerid: 5057159
< bbr1issuesprivate: 0
< bbr1haswrite: 1
< bbr1size: 896834063
< X-View-Name: bitbucket.gitweb.application
< Connection: Closed
< bbusername: user_name
< X-Usage-Input-Ops: 0
< bbr1owner: reponame
< bbr1id: 15508590
< 
* Closing connection 1
packet:          git< # service=git-upload-pack
packet:          git< 0000
packet:          git< be49ca012c0752031ced115cdad0af02931de2d0 HEAD\0multi_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed no-done symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master agent=git/2.7.4.1.g5468f9e
packet:          git< 36b228cb4d33d30cd536e7faddca8dc9c32e99fa refs/heads/develop
packet:          git< be49ca012c0752031ced115cdad0af02931de2d0 refs/heads/master
packet:          git< 0000
packet:          git> be49ca012c0752031ced115cdad0af02931de2d0 HEAD
packet:          git> 36b228cb4d33d30cd536e7faddca8dc9c32e99fa refs/heads/develop
packet:          git> be49ca012c0752031ced115cdad0af02931de2d0 refs/heads/master
packet:          git> 0000
packet:   fetch-pack< be49ca012c0752031ced115cdad0af02931de2d0 HEAD
packet:   fetch-pack< 36b228cb4d33d30cd536e7faddca8dc9c32e99fa refs/heads/develop
packet:   fetch-pack< be49ca012c0752031ced115cdad0af02931de2d0 refs/heads/master
packet:   fetch-pack< 0000
packet:   fetch-pack< be49ca012c0752031ced115cdad0af02931de2d0 HEAD\0multi_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed no-done symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master agent=git/2.7.4.1.g5468f9e
packet:   fetch-pack< 36b228cb4d33d30cd536e7faddca8dc9c32e99fa refs/heads/develop
packet:   fetch-pack< be49ca012c0752031ced115cdad0af02931de2d0 refs/heads/master
packet:   fetch-pack< 0000
packet:   fetch-pack> want be49ca012c0752031ced115cdad0af02931de2d0 multi_ack_detailed no-done side-band-64k thin-pack ofs-delta agent=git/1.9.1
packet:   fetch-pack> want 36b228cb4d33d30cd536e7faddca8dc9c32e99fa
packet:   fetch-pack> want be49ca012c0752031ced115cdad0af02931de2d0
packet:   fetch-pack> 0000
packet:   fetch-pack> done
packet:   fetch-pack> 0000
packet:          git< 007fwant be49ca012c0752031ced115cdad0af02931de2d0 multi_ack_detailed no-done side-band-64k thin-pack ofs-delta agent=git/1.9.10032want 36b228cb4d33d30cd536e7faddca8dc9c32e99fa0032want be49ca012c0752031ced115cdad0af02931de2d000000009done
packet:          git< 0000
* Couldn't find host bitbucket.org in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 104.192.143.2...
* Connected to bitbucket.org (104.192.143.2) port 443 (#2)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* SSL re-using session ID
*        server certificate verification OK
*        common name: bitbucket.org (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: 
*        start date: Tue, 03 May 2016 00:00:00 GMT

*        expire date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 12:00:00 GMT

*        issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*        compression: NULL
*        cipher: AES-128-CBC
*        MAC: SHA256
* Server auth using Basic with user '<user name>'
> POST /reponame.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic c3JlZWthbnRoX25jOnNyZWVrYW50aGhlcmU=
User-Agent: git/1.9.1
Host: bitbucket.org
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request
Accept: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
Content-Length: 240

* upload completely sent off: 240 out of 240 bytes
* GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
* Closing connection 2
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: What version of Git are you using on which OS? Is your remote repo a BitBucket one? a GitHub one?

Comment: Can you try cloning over ssh ?

Comment: You can get extra debug information from git by running `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git clone URL`.  It might help shed a little more light on what is happening.

Comment: Also, there were some fixes to Git's internal use of curl in 2.0.  You may want to try with a newer version of Git.

Comment: Please see edits, added the info that I get from GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git clone URL

Answer (score 0):

> error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0

This means that git tried to perform an HTTP operation, using the `libcurl` library, but the operation failed unexpectedly. Therefore, git is reporting the error code returned by `libcurl` ("result") and the HTTP error code.

In this case, the HTTP error code is 0, which usually means no HTTP error code was received (this is a minor git bug, it should not list an HTTP code).

The `libcurl` error code is 52. According to [the docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html), this means:

> CURLE_GOT_NOTHING (52) - 
>   Nothing was returned from the server, and under the circumstances,
>   getting nothing is considered an error.

**So in summary:** During an HTTP call, the remove server did not send a response when one was expected.

---

To find out more, you'll have to debug further. One good option, as explained in the comments, is to set `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1` when calling git - that will output extra information.

This is probably either a configuration problem on the git server, or you are using the wrong URI.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat: From the logs, it seems the actual upload of changes ("upload-pack") fails, because the server just closes the connection. I don't know why that happens, unfortunately.

Comment: The repo size is pretty huge. Could that be a reason?

Comment: Any way I switched to ssh to achieve a clone successfully.